# I want to dispatch 4 different value from Get service with different action. want to make one call

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to show 4 different array's data. I am calling get service but calling it 4 times. instead i want to make one call. with same link but want to dispatch 4 different actions for different data. as you can see there are 4 const which i want to dispatch and i have to make 4 calls right now. i am using initialload() as to reach to my view in Redux.

```
export function getcoCodeFilter() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(getServiceContext() + 'getfilteroptions', {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response
            .json()
            .then((json) => {
              const filterDisplay = json.data;
              const companyList = filterDisplay.companyCodes;
              const formtypeList = filterDisplay.formTypes;
              const yearList = filterDisplay.yearList;
              const qtrList = filterDisplay.quarterList;
              resolve(companyList);
            });
        }
        else {
          response
            .json()
            .then((json) => {
              const errors = json;
              reject(errors ? errors.exceptionMessages : []);
            });
        }
      });
  });
}

// get filter formtypes
export function getFormTypesFilter() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(getServiceContext() + 'getfilteroptions', {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response
            .json()
            .then((json) => {
              const coTypesList = json.data;
              resolve(coTypesList.formTypes);
            });
        }
        else {
          response
            .json()
            .then((json) => {
              const errors = json;
              reject(errors ? errors.exceptionMessages : []);
            });
        }
      });
  });
}

// get year for Filters
export function getYearFilter() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(getServiceContext() + 'getfilteroptions', {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response
            .json()
            .then((json) => {
              const coTypesList = json.data;
              resolve(coTypesList.yearList);
            });
        }
        else {
          response
            .json()
            .then((json) => {
              const errors = json;
              reject(errors ? errors.exceptionMessages : []);
            });
        }
      });
  });
}

// get quarters
export function getQTRFilter() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(getServiceContext() + 'getfilteroptions', {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response
            .json()
            .then((json) => {
              const coTypesList = json.data;
              resolve(coTypesList.quarterList);
            });
        }
        else {
          response
            .json()
            .then((json) => {
              const errors = json;
              reject(errors ? errors.exceptionMessages : []);
            });
        }
      });
  });
}


export const getInitialLoad = (dispatch) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {


    getcoCodeFilter().then((companyList) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'COCODE_FILTER_DISPLAY',
        value: companyList
      });

      resolve();
    });

    getFormTypesFilter().then((formtypeList) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FORMTYPES_FILTER_DISPLAY',
        value: formtypeList
      });

      resolve();
    });

    getYearFilter().then((yearList) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'YEAR_FILTER_DISPLAY',
        value: yearList
      });

      resolve();
    });

    getQTRFilter().then((qtrList) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'QTR_FILTER_DISPLAY',
        value: qtrList
      });

      resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What I often do is store all information in an object and dispatch an action with the object. The action will get picked up by one more many reducers.

something similar to this.

```
export const getInitialLoad = (dispatch) => {
    const ResponseData = {}
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      getcoCodeFilter().then((companyList) => {
        ResponseData["companyList"] = companyList;
        resolve();
      });

      getFormTypesFilter().then((formtypeList) => {
        ResponseData["formtypeList"] = formtypeList;
        resolve();
      });

      getYearFilter().then((yearList) => {
        ResponseData["yearList"] = yearList;
        resolve();
      });

      getQTRFilter().then((qtrList) => {
        ResponseData["qtrList"] = qtrList;
        dispatch({
          type: 'INITIAL_LOAD_ACTION',
          value: ResponseData
        });
        resolve();
      });
    });
  };
```

`INITIAL_LOAD_ACTION` can be called anything and used in any number of reducers. all you have to do is set the sate using something along the lines of

`action.payload.value.ResponseData` where `ResponseData` is one of the 4 keys you set above.

EDIT:

```
export const getInitialLoad = async (dispatch) => {
    const ResponseData = {}
    ResponseData["companyList"] = await  getcoCodeFilter();
    ResponseData["formtypeList"] = await  getFormTypesFilter();
    ResponseData["yearList"] = await  getYearFilter();
    ResponseData["qtrList"] = await  getQTRFilter(); 
    dispatch({
        type: 'INITIAL_LOAD_ACTION',
        value: ResponseData
    });
  };
```

OR you could do something like

```
export const getInitialLoad = async (dispatch) => {
    const ResponseData = await Promise.all([getcoCodeFilter, getFormTypesFilter, getYearFilter, getQTRFilter])
    dispatch({
        type: 'INITIAL_LOAD_ACTION',
        value: ResponseData
    });
  };
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: That sounds better. but still i will be displaying 4 categories. should i be doing eg componylist : action.value in reducer?

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate a little more? I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: I think you have mentioned how to access in reducer but  it still making 4 calls on the services. instead of that i just want to make one call

Comment: I mean, that's a matter of how you set up your server. to bulk all the calls in one, you would require a server that will be able to handle the API call. however, you could clean up the calls by using `async await`. Ill add the example above.